# Can ViewModel hold an indirect reference of the View via a ResourceDictionary URI?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control

WPF and MVVM are like body and soul. And it makes sense for `ViewModel` to be oblivious of the `View` that it may connect to (and vice versa).

But is it even a sin to hold reference of the View's Resource Dictionary inside a `ViewModel`. Does that defeat the purpose?

e.g. the code below is for POC purpose if VM can hold Views reference via resource dictionary. `ViewModel` can change this resource dictionary on the fly (based on certain input parameters).

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
   public interface IViewInjectingViewModel
   {
      void Initialize();
      URI ViewResourceDictionary { get; }
   }

   public class MyViewModel : IViewInjectingViewModel
   {
       private URI _viewResourceDictionary;
       public void Initialize()
       {
          _viewResourceDictionary = new URI("pack://application:,,,/MyApplication;component/Resources/MyApplicationViews.xaml");
        }

        public URI ViewResourceDictionary 
        {
           get
           {
              return _viewResourceDictionary;
           }
        }
   }
```

**MyApplicationViews.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock 
        Text="Portfolios" FontFamily="Verdana" 
        FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="6,7,6,4"/>
        <ListBox 
        Margin="2,1" SelectionMode="Single" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableTraders}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTrader}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
        <!-- ... -->
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window ...>
     <ContentControl 
    DataContext="{Binding myViewModel}"
    local:MyBehaviors.InjectView="true"/>
</Window>
```

**CommonBehaviors:**

```
public static class MyBehaviors
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InjectViewProperty 
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(..);

    //attached getters and setters...

    private static void OnInjectViewPropertyChanged(..)
    {
        var host = o as ContentControl;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            host.DataContextChanged
                += (o1, e1)  =>
                {
                    var viewInjectingVM = host.DataContext as IViewInjectingViewModel;
                    if (viewInjectingVM != null)
                    {
                        host.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
                        host.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( 
                            new ResourceDictionary() {    
                                Source = viewInjectingVM.ViewResourceDictionary 
                            });

                        host.Content = viewInjectingVM;
                    }
                };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll take a shot.  I think this is okay.  If you consider view-models to be part of the presentation layer, then having the view-model change a view's resource dictionary in response to some action is well within the MVVM paradigm.

Essentially you are changing the view's presentation in response to some action and the view-model has this responsibility.  So, updating the resource dictionary in this context seems like valid in the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I'd agree that this is OK in some cases, however I wouldn't say the ViewModel is part of the presentation layer, but rather the ResourceDictionary URI is part of the application layer.

Comment: @Rachel...I'm one of those that believe the view-model is part of the presentation layer.  How could it not be?  It's the engine that drives what the user sees on her screen.